# installing debian 10 on an existing SSD software raid0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, debian, raid

I'm trying to install the new Debian 10 (RC1) on my laptop using software raid0. The laptop is already running dualboot Win10 and Ubuntu. Now I want to install Debian 10 instead of Ubuntu, but for some reason the LiveCD does not recognize the raid configuration.

When I run gparted, I can see the md partitions. So my thinking is that I need to tell to the debian installer about my raid, but somehow I can't figure this out.

**root@debian:~# cat /proc/mdstat**

```
Personalities : [raid0] [linear] [multipath]
md126 : active raid0 sda[1] sdb[0]
      500113408 blocks super external:/md127/0 16k chunks

md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      4784 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

**cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf**

```
DEVICE /dev/sda* /dev/sdb*

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=e3120c67:e2074ddc:fd12b453:98272f9e
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume1 container=e3120c67:e2074ddc:fd12b453:98272f9e member=0 UUID=4707eb6a:5b32d5e0:553779dc:9e396eaa
```

**Raid in gparted:**
[disk partitions in gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDzV3.png)

**Raid not recognized in Debian-installer:**
[individual disks only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWeCj.png)

Anyone can advice how to force the debian installer to use the existing array?

Comment: It appears you have either a broken or partially active raid, which understandably screws with reading the raid properly in the installer

Comment: thank you... that's exactly what I said :) btw, the raid is active and the question was how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the installer is not supporting raids. So to install Debian with raid is to add the dmraid=true option in the boot window.